# mingw32-make.exe: how to execute powershell command in target instead of just output it as a string?

Tags: windows, powershell, makefile

How can I get this makefile to work the same on both linux and windows?

In Linux/Bash I'm running this command:

```bash
echo "the date and time is: $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
```

It outputs:

```
the date and time is: 2023-03-18 15:38:10
```

In Windows/PowerShell I'm running this command:

```
echo "the date and time is: $(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
```

It outputs:

```
the date and time is: 2023-03-18 15:39:47
```

Those commands are functionally equivalent.
Now I want to create a makefile that will cause make to run the respective command for Linux/Windows and get similar output on each.

I have created this makefile:

```
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
print-datetime:
    @echo "the date and time is: $$(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
else
print-datetime:
    @echo "the date and time is: $$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
endif
```

Now, when I run `make` on linux I get this output:

```
the date and time is: 2023-03-18 15:41:55
```

Which is good, this is what I wanted.

But, when I run `make` on windows (mingw32-make.exe from mingw), I get this output:

```
"the date and time is: $(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
```

Which is bad, this is not what I wanted.
Instead of running the command, it just prints the command string

How can I make mingw32-make.exe execute the command on powershell the same way that gnu make on linux executes the respective linux command on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make never uses the caller's shell to run commands.  That would be a portability nightmare.  On Windows (depending on how make was compiled) it will always use a POSIX shell if one can be found, else it will revert to using `cmd.exe`.

It will never use PowerShell on its own.

If you want to use a non-default shell, you have to set the `SHELL` variable in your makefile to whatever shell you want.

Comment: thanks, everything makes more sense now; setting SHELL = powershell made no difference though, what's the syntax for this?

Comment: make uses the command line `$(SHELL) $(.SHELLFLAGS) 'recipe'`.  By default `SHELL` is a POSIX shell if one can be found, and `.SHELLFLAGS` is `-c`.  If your shell needs a different syntax you'll have to make those changes.  I don't know Windows but this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe seems to say you need to set `.SHELLFLAGS = -Command`.

Comment: in the end looks like SHELL = powershell.exe worked for me. initially I didn't realize specifying the .exe is mandatory because usually windows doesn't care, but here it seems like this matters. thanks everyone

Comment: If you install PowerShell on Linux, the exact same command can be used on both Linux and Windows. Would that be a plus?